# PhoneGap Build Cannot get the device's properties phonegap/cordova

Tags: android, cordova

Hi I am new in phonegap/cordova I want to get device's object props from plugin from phonegap DeviceInformation but I cannot.
Here is my HTML `index.html`https://jsbin.com/nabuhopewo/edit?html,output

`alert("Test");` works, but device.some prop doesn't work, ie. `device.name` and so on.
What must be done?
Testing on physical device with platform android

fixed but not 100% 
`device.name` ->    I get `undefined`

name of device is Goclever Quantum 350 maybe because this smartphone is not popular?
and if I tested on Google Nexus or Samsung Galaxy then I would got one of these names?

in comments more

Comment: did u added the device plugin??? if yes remove it and install once again, the plugin  may not install properly some times

Comment: Could you post your code whatever you haver tried.

Comment: Yes I added earlier device plugin but after your comment @Naresh I commented in `config.xml`  `<gap:plugin name="com.vliesaputra.deviceinformation" spec="1.0.0" source="pgb" />` then build app and uncommented this <gap:plugin... and rebuild app, doesn't work. I included in `<script src="phonegap.js"></script>` or `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` the same. @jaydroider `index.html` here https://jsbin.com/nabuhopewo/edit?html,output  `config.xml` file here http://pastebin.com/pzS8wudc

Comment: I analyzed this carefully and result is using older version of plugin 0.3.0 
`<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />`
:| #$##%@$!, 
versions 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I analyzed this carefully and result is using older version of plugin 0.3.0 `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />` , versions 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 don't work in this case